# Calculus Integrals: Can you have v(s) instead of the typical v(t)?

Tags: calculus, integration

Quick question:

I am doing integrals with speed/velocity/acc.
You are given $v(t)$, with an initial condition $s(0)$, and need to figure out $s(t)$ via integrals (and determining C using the init. condition)

However, one problem gives the velocity func. in terms of s.
Specifically, $v = 8\sqrt{s}$ and $s(0)=9$  [initial position or displacement)

Not sure how to integrate this into s(t)

Normally, it's $v(t)$, not $v(s)$.   Is this a typo?

**Disclaimer**: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.

Comment: is s equal to the displacement?

Comment: Oh, ok, so just separate the variables first?  Where did the v go in the above equation?

Comment: Yes. For details please see the answers below. It is done usually early in the DE portion of a calculus book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!  Use $v = ds/dt$:

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 8 s^{1/2}$$

or

$$\int ds \, s^{-1/2} = 8 t$$

or

$$2 s^{1/2} = 8 t+C \implies s(t) = (4 t+C')^2$$

Comment: And since s(0)=9, C=3.    (Can I also use C=-3 or discard?)

Comment: @JackOfAll: Correct.  You can discard $C'=-3$ because of the original equation with $s^{1/2}$.

Comment: Right, but we're not saying s = -3, but that C' = -3.  That would make $s(t) = (4t-3)^2$ which is ok, right?

Comment: @JackOfAll: you're missing my point.  $C'$ cannot be negative because there will be a time at which $s^{1/2}$ will be negative, which cannot happen.  You have in essence chosen a branch of the square root that is positive.  So $C=3$ is the only choice.

Comment: Ron, I still don't see it.  There is no place where you're taking $\sqrt{C}$.  You're only taking $\sqrt{s}$ in the original equation which makes no reference to C, and in the very end above, where $C<0$ is perfectly acceptable, since it's not under a radical.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done a little later, it is an example of a differential equation where the variables can be separated. We get 
$$s^{-1/2}\frac{ds}{dt}=8.$$
Integrate with respect to $t$. On the left we get $2s^{1/2}$, on the right we get $8t+C$.

Comment: @jackofall to answer your comment from above, $v = 8dt$ as derived above